# Return variable class name from php factory

Tags: php, factory

I've got a `factory` that I want to return a `::class` from. However, the factory could potentially return a couple dozen different types (determined by the type of object passed into the factory), named `TypeOneObject`, `TypeTwoObject` etc. Is it possible to return the class using a variable, something like this?

```
$type = $myrequiredclass->getType();
return $type."Object"::class; // wanting TypeOneObject::class
```

It seems like no matter how I construct this return statement I always get `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '::'`

I know it'd be easy enough to do with a big `if/then` or `switch` but I'd like to avoid that.

Here's a more fleshed out scenario:

```
class TypeOneObject
{
    public static function whoAreYou()
    {
        return 'Type One Object!';
    }
}

class MyRequiredClass
{
    public function getType()
    {
        return 'TypeOne';
    }
}

class MyFactory
{
    public static function getFactoryObject(MyRequiredClass $class)
    {
        $type = $class->getType()."Object";
        return $type::class;
    }
}

$object = MyFactory::getFactoryObject(new MyRequiredClass());
$object::whoAreYou();
```

Comment: `{$type."Object"}::class` or perhaps with `()`? A [mcve] would have helped for easy testing.

Comment: What is in `$myrequiredclass`?

Comment: `$type::class;` What exactly are you thinking that the `::class` bit is doing there?  Just remove that and add an `echo` to your last line and you're all set.  That being said, I don't see the purpose of the factory in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to get the class name from the `$type` instance is to use php [get_class_methods](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) function. This will get us all the methods inside the class instance. from there we can filter and use `call_user_func` to call the method and get the right values.

```
class TypeOneObject
{
    public static function whoAreYou()
    {
        return 'Type One Object!';
    }
}

class MyRequiredClass
{
    public function getType()
    {
        return 'TypeOne';
    }
}

class MyFactory
{
    public static function getFactoryObject(MyRequiredClass $class)
    {
        $methods = get_class_methods($class);
        $method = array_filter($methods, function($method) {
            return $method == 'getType';
        });

        $class = new $class();
        $method = $method[0];
        $methodName = call_user_func([$class, $method]);
        $objectName = sprintf('%sObject', $methodName);

        return new $objectName;  
    }
}

$object = MyFactory::getFactoryObject(new MyRequiredClass());
echo $object::whoAreYou();
```

**Output**

`Type One Object!`